# Using Store Procedure with multiple result JPA

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jpa

I have two tables in SQL Server :

Table A

```
ID Num
11 tj55
4  tj40
```

Table B

```
ID NUM A_ID
3 se400 4
5 se500 4
```

I have a stored procedure which will return for each row in A all corresponding rows in B, I have this result

```
NumA NumB
tj40 se400
tj40 se500
```

Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc] 
    @param nvarchar(MAX),
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        aa.Num,
        bb.Num
    FROM 
        [dbo].[A]  as aa
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].[B] AS bb ON bb.A_ID = aa.ID 
    WHERE 
        aa.Num = @param
    ORDER BY 
        aa.Num
 END
```

I want to use a call my StoredProcedure in my Java application with JPA to have the two rows generated (my goal is to have List containing all the NumB (in this case 'se400' and 'se500')

```
StoredProcedureQuery query2 = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("Proc");
query2.registerStoredProcedureParameter("param", String.class,ParameterMode.IN);;
query2.setParameter("param", "tj40");

query2.execute();   

List<Object> res = query2.getResultList();
for (int i=0; i<res.size(); i++){
System.out.println(res.get(i).toString());
}
```

it founds the two rows but it returns

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@94814
[Ljava.lang.Object;@00856
```

Could you help me please?
Thank you very much

Comment: you mean, cast the result row to an Object[] ?!

Comment: My best scenario is to cast the result row in List<String>  (or Object but I will need to transform it as String then)

Comment: if a row is an Object[] why on earth would you cast it to (String)?!

Comment: I probably shoudln't have used the word "cast to String", I meant I need to access to the content of the Object like Object[1]... (in this case 'se400' and 'se500' values)

Answer (score 0):

In my application I am using the following way

```
List i1 = query2.getResultList();
while(i1.hasNext()){

    Object[] object =(Object[]) i1.next();
//your rest code
//object[0] will contain numA and object[1] will contain numB
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's absolutely what I need (object[0] will contain numA and object[1] will contain numB). But actually it doesn't work  : The method hasNext() is undefined for the type List and when I cast to Object it's the same

Comment: or (int i=0; i<i1.size(); i++)   {         
Object[] object = (Object[]) i1.get(i);   
} it is the same right?

Comment: @Learthgz I would prefer iterator instead of for loop